# Comprobating function not working as it should

Tags: javascript

I need to create a lottery game. I have an idea of how the whole code should be and it's mostly done, but I have a problem:

I have a button with an onclick called **generar()**, and this function, needs to draw 3 numbers from 1 to 999 and create along with the three numbers, another button which after pressing it, draws another number and then (the new button) checks the new number number with the ones who are already created to see if I won, or not.

Okay, I've managed to do the whole code, but the comparison of the three first numbers with the fourth number, doesn't work correctly. Always, the comprobation which says if I won or not, writes "¡Perdedor!" (looser!).

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Práctica 3</title>
        <style>
            #contenedor { border: 1px black solid;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 250px;
                    float: left;
                    margin-right: 5px; 
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-bottom: 5px; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contenedor"> <p id="primerNumero"/> </div>
        <div id="contenedor"> <p id="segundoNumero"/> </div>
        <div id="contenedor"> <p id="tercerNumero"/> </div>
        <button id="generar" onclick="generar()">Genera dècims</button>
        <div id="contenedor"> <p id="resultado"/> </div>
        <p id="t"/>

    <script>
        function generar() {
            var primerNumero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var segundoNumero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var tercerNumero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            var botones = document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").length;

            if (botones < 2) {
                generarBotones();   
            }

            document.getElementById("primerNumero").innerHTML = primerNumero;
            document.getElementById("primerNumero").style.fontSize = "72px";
            document.getElementById("segundoNumero").innerHTML = segundoNumero;
            document.getElementById("segundoNumero").style.fontSize = "72px";
            document.getElementById("tercerNumero").innerHTML = tercerNumero;
            document.getElementById("tercerNumero").style.fontSize = "72px";
        }

        function generarBotones() {
                var boton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                var t = document.createTextNode("Realizar sorteig");
                boton.onclick = function(){
                    var numeroGanador = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = numeroGanador;
                    document.getElementById("resultado").style.fontSize = "72px";
                    if(primerNumero == numeroGanador || segundoNumero == numeroGanador || tercerNumero == numeroGanador) {
                        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = "¡Ganador!";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = "¡Perdedor!";
                    }
                };  
                boton.appendChild(t);
                document.body.appendChild(boton);
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If somebody can tell me why and where I fail and a possible solution, it will be great. I will very grateful if an explanation is given too

Comment: My absolutely bad. The problem was that I wasn't using "primerNumero", "segundoNumero" and "tercerNumero" in the comparison, because I wasn't giving generarBotones() the variables as parameters. The solution was: 
if (botones < 2) { generarBotones(primerNumero, segundoNumero, tercerNumero) { generarBotones(); } and in function generarBotones (primerNumero, segundoNumero, tercerNumero) { ... }.
I'm so sorry!

Comment: Note that instead of having three variables and elements named with words, try using numbers: `num1`, `num2` and so on. That means you can write a simple loop to iterate over them rather than having to copy-paste huge chunks of code. It also means you can relate an array of values in a one-to-one way with these elements to avoid having multiple variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
primerNumero
segundoNumero
tercerNumero
```

Are html elements, not value, to get the value is necessary to use innerText OR innerHTML.

```
if(primerNumero.innerText == numeroGanador || segundoNumero.innerText == numeroGanador || tercerNumero.innerText == numeroGanador) {
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = "¡Ganador!";
} else {
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = "¡Perdedor!";
}
```

Or you can rename the variables to a different name of the element, because your problem is that the variables that contain the generated numbers are the same name as the id of the html element. If rename will work according to your first code.

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer is a valid answer to my thread, but I have resolved it anyways. primerNumero, segundoNumero and tercerNumero are not HTML elements, because they are created in the function generar();, so actually they are integer vars. At least, that's what I tried to do. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Your problem is that the variables that contain the generated numbers are the same name as the id of the html element.

Comment: You can add the debugger; in the line above if and check in the console.
This is a good tip for those starting in JS, many are not aware of this debugger function;

Comment: That's a great function! I wish I knew it before. This will be very useful in a future. Thanks.